# iOS 11 Black Bar on iPad when running iPhone App

Tags: ios, ipad, ios11

I submitted an update to my iPhone only app recently. However, it was rejected with this explanation:

> ## Guideline 2.4.1 - Performance - Hardware Compatibility
>
> We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when
>   reviewed on iPad running iOS 11.
>
> Please see attached screenshots for details.
>
> #### Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to ensure it runs and
>   displays properly at iPhone resolution on iPad. Even if your app was
>   developed specifically for iPhone, users should still be able to use
>   your app on iPad.
>
> #### Resources
>
> For information on iOS device screen sizes and resolutions, please
>   review the iOS Human Interface Guidelines as well as Points versus
>   Pixels in the View Programming Guide for iOS.
>
> You may also want to view Size Classes and Core Components for more
>   information about designing apps for multiple screen sizes.

I'm using a `Launch Screen.storyboard`, so there shouldn't be any issues with displaying, but I'm seeing a slightly transparent black bar at the top of my app, covering a portion of it.

What am I doing wrong? How do I remove it?

[image]

Comment: it's tough to guess what is wrong in the code but please check the app in iOS 10 iPad.

Comment: check your views layout constraints, the height is too big to fit on an iPad.

Comment: Are you using cordova ?

Comment: Nope, using native Swift code within Xcode.

Comment: Have same problem with cordova, seems related to ios11 safe-areas, as this bar's height is equal to [`constant(safe-area-inset-top)`](https://ayogo.com/blog/ios11-viewport/).